# ERRCONNREFUSED when connecting Mongodb in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, atlas

I am trying to set up MongoDB with Node.js and I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught MongooseServerSelectionError MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at MongooseError (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:7:1)
    at MongooseServerSelectionError (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:26:1)
    at Connection.openUri (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:824:32)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:381:10)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5)
    at promiseOrCallback (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1234:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:20)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\lilpi\mongo\app.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest')
```

Here is my database connection:
[image: mongodb connection]

This is my first time attempting to use MongoDB and I am very new to node.js and programming as a whole, so the solution is probably very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to connect to a MongoDB server running on `localhost` (which is your local machine), but your screenshot is showing an entirely different hostname.

So make sure you're actually using the correct hostname:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mydb.kngo05j.mongodb.net/mongotest')
```

You may also need to pass login credentials. How to do that is explained [in the Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me on MAC:

```
brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@"yourmongoversion"
```